# How to put a simple JS widget/gadget block on a Nuxtjs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

Some services like Google Analytics or Statcounter give a basic code to add to the website. What is the best way to integrate this type script blocks to the Nuxtjs based webapps/sites?

An example code block from Statcounter to add Nuxtjs;

```
<!-- Default Statcounter code for project
http://www.example.com -->
<script type="text/javascript">
var sc_project=1234567; 
var sc_invisible=1; 
var sc_security="abcdefg"; 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="https://www.statcounter.com/counter/counter.js"
async></script>
<noscript><div class="statcounter"><a title="Web Analytics"
href="https://statcounter.com/" target="_blank"><img
class="statcounter"
src="https://c.statcounter.com/1234567/0/abcdefg/1/"
alt="Web Analytics"></a></div></noscript>
<!-- End of Statcounter Code -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add external resources using the `nuxt.config.js`: https://nuxtjs.org/faq/#global-settings

For example:

```
// nuxt.config.js

export default {
  head: {
    script: [
      { src: 'https://www.statcounter.com/counter/counter.js', async: true },
      { src: '/customscript.js' } // customscript.js located in "static/" directory
    ]
  }
}
```

You can also add these in a component. For example, if the `<noscript>` has to go in the body, you can add `body: true`: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/blob/dev/examples/meta-info/pages/index.vue#L18

Comment: Thank you very much. By the way, this script should work on every page; so for Nuxtjs, this should work on every state/route change. Is it possible with these ways?

Comment: You're welcome! If you add it in the `head` tag through `nuxt.config.js`, the script _should_ work for every page (since it's global, it will be in the `<head>` tag in every page). Otherwise, you may need to look at nuxt middlewares: https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-middleware/ to work with route/state specific changes.